# Pandas accessing last non-null value

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to fill data frame NaNs with the last valid value for a given group. For instance:

```
import pandas as pd
import random as randy
import numpy as np

df_size = int(1e1)                
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': randy.sample(np.repeat(['Strawberry','Apple',],df_size),df_size), 'values': randy.sample(np.repeat([np.NaN,0,1],df_size),df_size)}, index=randy.sample(np.arange(0,10),df_size)).sort_index(by=['category'], ascending=[True])
```

Delivers:

```
     category   value
7       Apple     NaN
6       Apple       1
4       Apple       0
5       Apple     NaN
1       Apple     NaN
0  Strawberry       1
8  Strawberry     NaN
2  Strawberry       0
3  Strawberry       0
9  Strawberry     NaN
```

And the column I wish to calculate looks like this:

```
     category   value  last_value
7       Apple     NaN         NaN
6       Apple       1         NaN
4       Apple       0           1
5       Apple     NaN           0
1       Apple     NaN           0
0  Strawberry       1         NaN
8  Strawberry     NaN           1
2  Strawberry       0           1
3  Strawberry       0           0
9  Strawberry     NaN           0
```

Tried `shift()` and `iterrows()` but to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want to first do a [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html?highlight=ffill#filling-while-reindexing) then do a [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
In [11]: df['value'].ffill()
Out[11]:
7   NaN
6     1
4     0
5     0
1     0
0     1
8     1
2     0
3     0
9     0
Name: value, dtype: float64

In [12]: df['value'].ffill().shift(1)
Out[12]:
7   NaN
6   NaN
4     1
5     0
1     0
0     0
8     1
2     1
3     0
9     0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

To do this over each *group* you have to groupby category first and then apply this function:

```
In [13]: g = df.groupby('category')

In [14]: g['value'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().shift(1))
Out[14]:
7   NaN
6   NaN
4     1
5     0
1     0
0   NaN
8     1
2     1
3     0
9     0
dtype: float64

In [15]: df['last_value'] = g['value'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().shift(1))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants this trick pulled on the groups from `df.groupby("category")`, which may explain the third NaN.

Comment: @DSM :) seems so obvious now!