# Pandas: Get Grouped and Conditioned Last Value

Tags: sql, pandas, pandas-groupby

In the following dataset (as a dictionary - use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` )

```
{'customer_id': {0: 33179018, 1: 33179018, 2: 33179018, 3: 33179018, 4: 33179018, 5: 33179018, 6: 33179018, 7: 33179018, 8: 33179018, 9: 33179018, 10: 33179018, 11: 33179018, 12: 33179018, 13: 33179018, 14: 33179018, 15: 33179018, 16: 33179018, 17: 33179018, 18: 33179018, 19: 33179018, 20: 33179018, 21: 33179018, 22: 33179018, 23: 33179018, 24: 33179018, 25: 33179018, 26: 33179018, 27: 33179018, 28: 33179018, 29: 33179018}, 'binned_due_date': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), 12: Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), 13: Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), 14: Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), 15: Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), 16: Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), 17: Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), 18: Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), 19: Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), 20: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 21: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 22: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 23: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 24: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 25: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 26: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 27: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 28: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 29: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00')}, 'days_after_due_date': {0: 0, 1: 7, 2: 15, 3: 30, 4: 45, 5: 60, 6: 90, 7: 120, 8: 150, 9: 180, 10: 0, 11: 7, 12: 15, 13: 30, 14: 45, 15: 60, 16: 90, 17: 120, 18: 150, 19: 180, 20: 0, 21: 7, 22: 15, 23: 30, 24: 45, 25: 60, 26: 90, 27: 120, 28: 150, 29: 180}, 'delinquency': {0: 0.2867237699667474, 1: 0.2111735340275364, 2: 0.1403712350605344, 3: 0.0159991170314348, 4: 0.0114093576839494, 5: 0.0114093576839494, 6: 0.0114093576839494, 7: 0.0096316009774459, 8: 0.0078538442709424, 9: 0.0078538442709424, 10: 0.0941250733801591, 11: 0.0823426447122737, 12: 0.0659927025855154, 13: 0.0415580671739743, 14: 0.0415580671739743, 15: 0.0415580671739743, 16: 0.038385027182922006, 17: 0.0352119871918695, 18: 0.0352119871918695, 19: 0.0280579446625502, 20: 0.0895907764209953, 21: 0.0854471519423207, 22: 0.0718793634721559, 23: 0.0663738935651319, 24: 0.0613301602549993, 25: 0.04804977925841, 26: 0.042425938521263, 27: 0.042425938521263, 28: 0.0355907007772587, 29: 0.0355907007772587}}
```

For each Customer (`customer_id`), get the value of `delinquency` in the previous month `(t - 1)` where `days_after_due_date == 7`. Also I need to get the value of `delinquency` 2 months ago `(t - 2)` where `days_after_due == 30`, **for each row in my dataset**.

```
customer_id          binned_due_date days_after_due_date  delinquency
0      33179018      2020-01-01                    0     0.286724
1      33179018      2020-01-01                    7     0.211174
2      33179018      2020-01-01                   15     0.140371
3      33179018      2020-01-01                   30     0.015999
4      33179018      2020-01-01                   45     0.011409
5      33179018      2020-01-01                   60     0.011409
6      33179018      2020-01-01                   90     0.011409
7      33179018      2020-01-01                  120     0.009632
8      33179018      2020-01-01                  150     0.007854
9      33179018      2020-01-01                  180     0.007854
10     33179018      2020-02-01                    0     0.094125
11     33179018      2020-02-01                    7     0.082343
12     33179018      2020-02-01                   15     0.065993
13     33179018      2020-02-01                   30     0.041558
14     33179018      2020-02-01                   45     0.041558
15     33179018      2020-02-01                   60     0.041558
16     33179018      2020-02-01                   90     0.038385
17     33179018      2020-02-01                  120     0.035212
18     33179018      2020-02-01                  150     0.035212
19     33179018      2020-02-01                  180     0.028058
20     33179018      2020-03-01                    0     0.089591
21     33179018      2020-03-01                    7     0.085447
22     33179018      2020-03-01                   15     0.071879
23     33179018      2020-03-01                   30     0.066374
24     33179018      2020-03-01                   45     0.061330
25     33179018      2020-03-01                   60     0.048050
26     33179018      2020-03-01                   90     0.042426
27     33179018      2020-03-01                  120     0.042426
28     33179018      2020-03-01                  150     0.035591
29     33179018      2020-03-01                  180     0.035591
```

In SQL tried the following, but doesn't works exactly the way I described, and for me would be better to do it using Pandas.

```sql
LAST_VALUE(IF (days_after_due_date = 7, delinquency, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
        PARTITION BY observed.customer_id ORDER BY observed.binned_due_date, observed.days_after_due_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) last_i7,
```

The desired output would be (requested by @Umar.h):

[image]

Comment: can you add your output please?

Comment: This should answer most of those questions for you : [Pandas accessing last non-null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816754/pandas-accessing-last-non-null-value)  *(for actual code to do the full logic, you should include the desired results you want, not just the data you start with)*

Comment: Sorry, just updated because I forgot to add it @MatBailie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Approach

```
c = ['customer_id', 'binned_due_date']

t1 = df[df['days_after_due_date'] == 7].copy()
t1['binned_due_date'] += pd.DateOffset(months=1)

t2 = df[df['days_after_due_date'] == 30].copy()
t2['binned_due_date'] += pd.DateOffset(months=2)

df['d7 t-1']  = df.set_index(c).index.map(t1.set_index(c)['delinquency'])
df['d30 t-2'] = df.set_index(c).index.map(t2.set_index(c)['delinquency'])
```

#### Explanations

---

- Query the dataframe to select the rows where `days_after_due_date` is `7`, lets call this dataframe `t1`
- Add a date offset of `1` months to the `binned_due_date` column so that we could be able to map the `delinquency` value for the current month to the next month
- In the similar fashion, generate another dataframe `t2` so that we could be able to map the delinquency value for the current month to two month afterwards
- Map the `delinquency` values from `t1` and `t2` to the given dataframe based on the common `'customer_id'` and `'binned_due_date'`

#### Result

```
    customer_id binned_due_date  days_after_due_date  delinquency    d7 t-1   d30 t-2
0      33179018      2020-01-01                    0     0.286724       NaN       NaN
1      33179018      2020-01-01                    7     0.211174       NaN       NaN
2      33179018      2020-01-01                   15     0.140371       NaN       NaN
3      33179018      2020-01-01                   30     0.015999       NaN       NaN
4      33179018      2020-01-01                   45     0.011409       NaN       NaN
5      33179018      2020-01-01                   60     0.011409       NaN       NaN
6      33179018      2020-01-01                   90     0.011409       NaN       NaN
7      33179018      2020-01-01                  120     0.009632       NaN       NaN
8      33179018      2020-01-01                  150     0.007854       NaN       NaN
9      33179018      2020-01-01                  180     0.007854       NaN       NaN
10     33179018      2020-02-01                    0     0.094125  0.211174       NaN
11     33179018      2020-02-01                    7     0.082343  0.211174       NaN
12     33179018      2020-02-01                   15     0.065993  0.211174       NaN
13     33179018      2020-02-01                   30     0.041558  0.211174       NaN
14     33179018      2020-02-01                   45     0.041558  0.211174       NaN
15     33179018      2020-02-01                   60     0.041558  0.211174       NaN
16     33179018      2020-02-01                   90     0.038385  0.211174       NaN
17     33179018      2020-02-01                  120     0.035212  0.211174       NaN
18     33179018      2020-02-01                  150     0.035212  0.211174       NaN
19     33179018      2020-02-01                  180     0.028058  0.211174       NaN
20     33179018      2020-03-01                    0     0.089591  0.082343  0.015999
21     33179018      2020-03-01                    7     0.085447  0.082343  0.015999
22     33179018      2020-03-01                   15     0.071879  0.082343  0.015999
23     33179018      2020-03-01                   30     0.066374  0.082343  0.015999
24     33179018      2020-03-01                   45     0.061330  0.082343  0.015999
25     33179018      2020-03-01                   60     0.048050  0.082343  0.015999
26     33179018      2020-03-01                   90     0.042426  0.082343  0.015999
27     33179018      2020-03-01                  120     0.042426  0.082343  0.015999
28     33179018      2020-03-01                  150     0.035591  0.082343  0.015999
29     33179018      2020-03-01                  180     0.035591  0.082343  0.015999
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# One row per customer/due_date, with columns for 7 and 30 days
df_pivot = df[df['days_after_due_date'].isin([7, 30])].pivot(index=['customer_id','binned_due_date'],columns='days_after_due_date',values='delinquency').reset_index()

# Offset by one or two rows (only within the same customer)
df_pivot['7_lag_1'] = df_pivot.groupby('customer_id')[7].shift(1)
df_pivot['30_lag_2'] = df_pivot.groupby('customer_id')[30].shift(2)

# Merge back on to original set
df.merge(df_pivot, on=['customer_id','binned_due_date'], how='left')
```

Note: The data must already be in Customer, DueDate, DaysAfterDueDate order.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better way, but here is one:

```
>>> df['d7 t-1'] = df.query('days_after_due_date == [7]')[['delinquency']].shift(1)
>>> df['d30 t-2'] = df.query('days_after_due_date == [30]')[['delinquency']].shift(1)
>>> df.ffill().fillna('-')

    customer_id binned_due_date  days_after_due_date  delinquency     d7 t-1    d30 t-2
0      33179018      2020-01-01                    0     0.286724          -          -
1      33179018      2020-01-01                    7     0.211174          -          -
2      33179018      2020-01-01                   15     0.140371          -          -
3      33179018      2020-01-01                   30     0.015999          -          -
4      33179018      2020-01-01                   45     0.011409          -          -
5      33179018      2020-01-01                   60     0.011409          -          -
6      33179018      2020-01-01                   90     0.011409          -          -
7      33179018      2020-01-01                  120     0.009632          -          -
8      33179018      2020-01-01                  150     0.007854          -          -
9      33179018      2020-01-01                  180     0.007854          -          -
10     33179018      2020-02-01                    0     0.094125          -          -
11     33179018      2020-02-01                    7     0.082343   0.211174          -
12     33179018      2020-02-01                   15     0.065993   0.211174          -
13     33179018      2020-02-01                   30     0.041558   0.211174  0.0159991
14     33179018      2020-02-01                   45     0.041558   0.211174  0.0159991
15     33179018      2020-02-01                   60     0.041558   0.211174  0.0159991
16     33179018      2020-02-01                   90     0.038385   0.211174  0.0159991
17     33179018      2020-02-01                  120     0.035212   0.211174  0.0159991
18     33179018      2020-02-01                  150     0.035212   0.211174  0.0159991
19     33179018      2020-02-01                  180     0.028058   0.211174  0.0159991
20     33179018      2020-03-01                    0     0.089591   0.211174  0.0159991
21     33179018      2020-03-01                    7     0.085447  0.0823426  0.0159991
22     33179018      2020-03-01                   15     0.071879  0.0823426  0.0159991
23     33179018      2020-03-01                   30     0.066374  0.0823426  0.0415581
24     33179018      2020-03-01                   45     0.061330  0.0823426  0.0415581
25     33179018      2020-03-01                   60     0.048050  0.0823426  0.0415581
26     33179018      2020-03-01                   90     0.042426  0.0823426  0.0415581
27     33179018      2020-03-01                  120     0.042426  0.0823426  0.0415581
28     33179018      2020-03-01                  150     0.035591  0.0823426  0.0415581
29     33179018      2020-03-01                  180     0.035591  0.0823426  0.0415581
```

Comment: But this method won't work with a `groupby('customer_id')`

Comment: I am sorry, I must have misunderstood... The solution provided matches exactly your desired output. I was not aware there were different customer ids (at least not provided within your example). Nevertheless, you can easily do something similar using `groupby`. Right now I need to go, but will provide something later-on.

Comment: These results manifestly don't match what the OP has posted.  In the OP, `d7_t-1` should have a value in row 10, `d30 t-2` should start at row 20, not row 13.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I have rushed it as I had to go out put wanted to get it published. I see there are other solutions provided now so I will probably delete my answer.